# AES Encryption theory and calculation

Tags: aes

(a) Briefly explain the following round transformations of AES Encryption. Please indicate
if it helps diffusion or confusion or both.

SubBytes
ShiftRows
MixColumns
AddRoundKey
(b) Suppose you are computing one round of AES. In MixColums step, one row of your input
is 21A07C3D. Compute the multiplication of 03010102 by 21A07C3D.
Note that: The irreducible polynomial is P (x) = x 8 + x 4 + x 3 + x + 1.